# MySQL copy values to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, syntax-error, inner-join

I need to copy Klient_ID values from table(Klient) to table(Kliendikaart). Command should choose ID by correct first name('Eesnimi'). I tried this command:

```
UPDATE Kliendikaart
SET Kliendikaart.Klient_ID = Klient.Klient_ID
FROM Kliendikaart
INNER JOIN Klient ON Kliendikaart.Eesnimi = Klient.Eesnimi;
```

but

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; ... near 'FROM Kliendikaart
>   INNER JOIN Klient ON Kliendikaart.Eesnimi = Klient.Eesnimi' at line 1

Tables:

```
select * from Kliendikaart;
+-----------------+-----------+---------+----------+
| Kliendikaart_ID | Klient_ID | Eesnimi | Perenimi |
+-----------------+-----------+---------+----------+
|               1 |      NULL | Priit   | Triip    |
|               2 |      NULL | Tõnu    | Lepp     |
|               3 |      NULL | Tiit    | Kask     |
|               4 |      NULL | Linda   | Orb      |
|               5 |      NULL | Salme   | Kepp     |
|               6 |      NULL | Iiris   | Toos     |
|               7 |      NULL | Kertu   | Verb     |
|               8 |      NULL | Triinu  | Kolk     |
|               9 |      NULL | Tõnis   | Viip     |
|              10 |      NULL | Taavi   | Kolk     |
+-----------------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

and

```
select * from Klient;
+-----------+---------+----------+
| Klient_ID | Eesnimi | Perenimi |
+-----------+---------+----------+
|         1 | Priit   | Triip    |
|         2 | Tõnu    | Lepp     |
|         3 | Tiit    | Kask     |
|         4 | Linda   | Orb      |
|         5 | Salme   | Kepp     |
|         6 | Iiris   | Toos     |
|         7 | Kertu   | Verb     |
|         8 | Triinu  | Kolk     |
|         9 | Tõnis   | Viip     |
|        10 | Taavi   | Kolk     |
+-----------+---------+----------+
```

The output should look like this:

```
select * from Kliendikaart;
+-----------------+-----------+---------+----------+
| Kliendikaart_ID | Klient_ID | Eesnimi | Perenimi |
+-----------------+-----------+---------+----------+
|               1 |         1 | Priit   | Triip    |
|               2 |         2 | Tõnu    | Lepp     |
|               3 |         3 | Tiit    | Kask     |
|               4 |         4 | Linda   | Orb      |
|               5 |         5 | Salme   | Kepp     |
|               6 |         6 | Iiris   | Toos     |
|               7 |         7 | Kertu   | Verb     |
|               8 |         8 | Triinu  | Kolk     |
|               9 |         9 | Tõnis   | Viip     |
|              10 |        10 | Taavi   | Kolk     |
+-----------------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

Tables which I created are using these keys:

```
create table Klient(
Klient_ID int unsigned not null auto_increment,
Eesnimi varchar(30) not null,
Perenimi varchar(30) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (Klient_ID));

create table Kliendikaart(
Kliendikaart_ID int unsigned not null auto_increment,
Klient_ID integer unsigned,
Eesnimi varchar(30) not null,
Perenimi varchar(30) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (Kliendikaart_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Klient_ID) references Klient(Klient_ID));
```

Comment: Have a look at the manual under UPDATE syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
UPDATE Kliendikaart kd
INNER JOIN Klient k ON kd.Eesnimi = k.Eesnimi
SET kd.Klient_ID = k.Klient_ID;
```

Your query is for SQL Server, not for My SQL. And you should use alias for short and easy to read query.

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, there is a syntax difference between mysql and sql server:

```
UPDATE Kliendikaart
INNER JOIN Klient ON Kliendikaart.Eesnimi = Klient.Eesnimi
SET Kliendikaart.Klient_ID = Klient.Klient_ID;
```